# Is it possible to use multiple files to define eam potential in LAMMPS?

Tags: lammps, interatomic-potentials

I have been trying to model ZrNiSn Half Heusler using the eam potential in LAMMPS MD package. For this I use a single eam potential file with the descriptions of all the species available in it. Also, I want to see the effect of the addition of Ti atoms on the thermal conductivity. However, the eam potential file which I have supports only Zr, Ni and Sn.

Even though I can find the eam potential for Ti on the [internet](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/potentials/system/Tl/), I am not sure about the ability of LAMMPS to model the Ti interactions with other species.

Can someone confirm whether it is possible to use such a separate file to model the Ti interactions. Would LAMMPS be supplied with the required data on the interactions of Ti with other species if this is done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, It is not recommended to mix two inter-atomic potential, Let me go through the consequences, You want to mix $\ce{Ti}$  `EAM` potential to $\ce{Zr-Ni-Sn}$. You can do simply in lammps using pair style/overlays
For example

```
pair_style hybrid lj/cut/coul/cut 10.0 eam lj/cut 5.0
pair_coeff 1*2 1*2 eam niu3
pair_coeff 3 3 lj/cut/coul/cut 1.0 1.0
pair_coeff 1*2 3 lj/cut 0.5 1.2
```

But Do you know interaction parameters for $\ce{Ti}$ with $\ce{Zr}$,$\ce{Ni}$ and $\ce{Sn}$. In broader sense, for `EAM` potential, you need three thing

1. **Embedded function**
2. **Density function**
3. **Pair-wise interaction**

Even If embedded function/density of $\ce{Ti}$ is same as $\ce{Zr}$, $\ce{Ni}$, $\ce{Sn}$, you must know pairwise parameters for $\ce{Zr-Ti}$, $\ce{Ni-Ti}$ and $\ce{Sn-Ti}$ for `EAM/alloy`. Things will be difficult if you want `EAM/fs` where density function for each cross-term is needed. Don't forget, all parameters should also be fitted for some properties as well. It is also worthy to note that fitting X number of parameters of material doesn't guarantee to give qualitative results for different Y number of parameters.